# Unfair reduction process

Tags: recruitment, human-resources, discrimination

My wife has worked in a senior position for about 6 years. She is the most experienced person in the department and has high degree qualifications. This month, the company announced it will reduce employment from 6 to 2 people per shift. There are other jobs in the business they can apply for if they like, or they can take redundancy.

Some people just took the money. My wife decided to apply for some jobs. One of the positions was a job she has done some years ago.
Yesterday she got a decision from HR that she was not promoted to any of the jobs she applied for, and she can step down to production level. The position will be taken by people with much less experience and education level.

My wife never had any disciplinary action against her or was late or even sick (ok she was once for Covid which she picked up at work anyway.) Is there anything we can do to find out why she was refused?

Comment: For what reason do you think this was discrimination?

Comment: Not yet as she have decisions announced yesterday just before finish and she was so stressed.

Comment: Comic Sans Seraphim well it’s my feeling as I can’t se reason why she was refused.

Comment: Discrimination on what grounds though? Gender? Race? Something else? Unlawful discrimination is more than "this seems unfair".

Comment: Well you my right I my take this to much personally but I have feelings it’s not right and I don’t know what to do that right my question

Comment: @JoeStrazzere In the original post OP mentions they are not British therefore the UK is a safe assumption (at least until OP confirms it).

Comment: This might be constructive dismissal.

Comment: @C'estMoi Unlikely.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie  Quite likely I think.  "a unilateral and substantial alteration of a fundamental term or condition of his/her employment."  https://www.canada.ca/en/employment-social-development/programs/laws-regulations/labour/interpretations-policies/constructive-dismissal.html


https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructive_dismissal

Answer (score 5):

> It’s there anything we can do to find out why she was refused and dragging down this way?

If there is no official process (and you gave no indication that there was, either through government regulations in your part of the world and specific industry, or through a union in the industry and specific company) then no.

Please note that there is no requirement for a company to make "fair" decisions. While laws may regulate what the company *cannot* disrciminate against (sex, age, religion are common), there is no law anywhere that says a company has to be objective in their choice. They can pick someone else over your wife for any unfair reason they want, as long as it's not one prohibited by law.

> also they announced that the position will be taken by persons with lots less experience and education level

See, what they also announced in that statement was that they chose people that are way *cheaper* than your wife. If they deem their level of work "enough" for their business, that might even be a reasonable decision on their end. Matter of fact, since they were forced to downsize, being cheap might be *all* that mattered.

That said, look at it in a positive light: that company had to restructure and lay off people. And one layoff is never enough. There will be a next round and a next round of shrinking the business and letting people go. Your wife will be way better off with another company, that actually *grows* their business, pays proper wages and offers some job security.

Comment: Agree with you 100% and I’m doing all my best to help her go to this point but it’s still this feeling that you spend 5 years doing the best you can and on end of day you are threat like rubbish.

Comment: Welcome, alas, to capitalism.

Answer (score 2):

As presented, this is neither unfair nor discrimination; experience and education level are not the sole judge of whether someone is qualified to do a job or not.

If you can show that your wife was actually better at the job than the other applicants, then you might have something to go on but at the moment you're arguments are flimsy at best.

Comment: Right but in this case we are talking about internal requirements where for example you have persons working 5 years as senior technician with no problem due work lots of knowledge and persons working 1 year as technical the same department and because of reduction they interview both and chase persons second person it’s that everything looks right for u

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, if you want to find out why she was refused (which is the question you asked), all you can do is ask the company and/or individuals in the company who might know -- and they are under no obligation to tell you. Indeed management may have been instructed not to comment.

This happens to many of us at some point in our careers. Becoming more senior is no protection; indeed since that tends to make us more expensive it may increase the amount that a company thinks it can save by letting us go, despite the fact that it also makes us more productive.

If this was part of a large "headcount reduction" action, and you can find a clear pattern in those reductions which might discriminate against a protected class of people, there might be grounds for a lawsuit; in the US this tends to becomes a class-action lawsuit if many people were involved, though that has its own problems. My own ex-employer has been hit with enough of those
.. But that's a better topic for the Law stack than here.

Unfortunately, the days of companies, especially large companies, seeing themselves as families is long past. No matter how much loyalty you have to the company, do not expect the company to reciprocate, and be prepared to disengage when necessary. "It's just business."

Answer (score 0):

I sympathize, I truly do.

The issue that you need to confront is how much more suited to the role your wife was vs the person that got the job.

The threshold for discrimination is difficult and very high. If you have two somewhat evenly matched candidates (even with a couple of years experience difference) - an Employer could justify their decision in a number of different ways - none of which would be illegal.

To pass the threshold of unlawful discrimination, the difference in skills and abilities would have to be overwhelmingly obvious.

For example - if there was a job that involved a lot of Sprinting and it was yours truly against Usain Bolt - and the Employer turned to Mr Bolt and said "Thank you very much, your resume was very impressive, but we believe Mr DemonLord to be a better fit" - Usain could definitely sue on discrimination.

But unless there is such a measurable and demonstrable capability difference - it's more likely that your Wife should take the loss and move on (ideally to a better paying role with another company that respects her skills and experience).

And the only way to find out if it's such a big difference would be to start a civil suit and go through the process of discovery. Unless you want to pay for the costs of a Lawsuit - you'd likely out of luck.